# How do i change timer interval in mouse wheel event to fast and slow?

Tags: c#, winforms

The code:

```
private void Form1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (leave == true)
            {
                timer1.Interval = 10;
            }
        }
```

I want to do that if i turn the mouse wheel to my side down it will slow the timer will increase the interval and if i turn the wheel up it will decrease the interval.

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`MouseEventArgs.Delta`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.delta.aspx) property

> The mouse wheel combines the features of a wheel and a mouse button.
>   The wheel has discrete, evenly spaced notches. When you rotate the
>   wheel, a wheel message is sent as each notch is encountered. One wheel
>   notch, a detent, is defined by the windows constant WHEEL_DELTA, which
>   is 120. **A positive value indicates that the wheel was rotated
>   forward (away from the user); a negative value indicates that the
>   wheel was rotated backward (toward the user).**

```
private void Form1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Delta > 0) //moved forward
    {
        timer1.Interval += 1000;
    }
    else //moved backword
    {
        timer1.Interval -= 1000;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am also interested in the downvote. If the down-voter has another way of doing it please share or if you disagree with the method `MouseEventArgs.Delta` please state why.

Comment: I didn't downvote this, I just want to comment that maybe the downvote was for the `lengthy` code (lengthy but easy to understand for newbies), not for using `MouseEventArgs.Delta`, the code can be simpler as `timer1.Interval -= (-e.Delta*1000)/e.Delta;`, or if we don't care much about the exact increment/decrement of `Interval` we can simply use `timer1.Interval += e.Delta*10;` (=1200), anyway I would like to give this answer +1

Comment: @KingKing, Thank you :), I thought about use `Delta` value in my code, but then decided to use `if` for clarity.

Comment: Well, missed that, it's `timer1.Interval += (e.Delta*1000)/Math.Abs(e.Delta);` :)

Answer (score 1):

`MouseEventArgs.Delta`  Checks how much the mouse has been moved. If *delta* is positive increase speed, if *delta* is negative decrease speed.

The link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.delta.aspx) shows how to use *delta* using C#

Mousewheel
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousewheel.aspx